# Maps Geocoder GetAddressesForPositionAsync Returns Nothing on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193. The call to GetAddressesForPositionAsync always returns null for Android. It works fine for iOS and UWP. I've only tried on the Visual Studio emulator, but the other platforms work with the emulators/simulators. I have set a location in the emulator. Anything I'm missing?

Same situation for GetPositionsForAddressAsync.

I have the map API key entered in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```html
 <application android:label="My.Mobile.XamarinForms.Droid">
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="My API Key" />
 </application>
```